# Leaflet: layer.getLatLng not working with .eachLayer function

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet, radius

I'm trying to do something very similar to what Chris Essig did [here](https://csessig.wordpress.com/2014/06/22/leaflet-solution-counting-markers-within-a-radius/). Because I need to know how much datapoints there are in a radius of 20 meters from where the user has put down the 'trashMarker'.

So far I've got this code:

```
// Create the FeatureGroup and add it to the map
var jsonGroup = new L.FeatureGroup();
mapOverview.addLayer(jsonGroup)

//Retrieve all data and add to map
$.each(datalistObject['idlist'], function(key, value) { 
    $.getJSON('http://mydata.com' + value['id'], function(data) {
        textbox = value['name'];

        var dataid = L.geoJson([data], {
            style: function (feature) {
                return feature.properties && feature.properties.style;
            },
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
            pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
                return L.marker(latlng, {
                    icon: value['icon']
                });
            }
        }).addTo(jsonGroup);

    },function(xhr) { console.error(xhr); });
});

//Code to find the markers within a 20 meter radius of trashMarker
function markersInRadius() {

        // Lat, long of trash marker on overview map
        var trashMarkerLat_long = trashMarkerOverview.getLatLng();

        // counter of the amount of markers that are within a 20 meter radius
        var counter_markers_in_radius = 0;

        console.log(jsonGroup);

        // Loop through each point in JSON file
        jsonGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {

            // Lat, long of current point
            layerLatLong = layer.getLatLng();

            // Distance from our circle marker
            // To current point in meters
            distance_from_layer_circle = layerLatLong.distanceTo(trashMarker_lat_long);

            // See if meters is within raduis
            // The user has selected
            if (distance_from_layer_circle <= 20) {
                counter_markers_in_radius += 1;
            };

            console.log(counter_markers_in_radius);
        });
// Close pointsInCircle
};
```

When I run this code, I get the error saying layer.getLatLng is not a function.

After doing a console.log on the jsonGroup FeatureGroup, I found out that the group has two objects in it's layers tab without any latlng information, but instead a layers tab of its own, containing all the datapoints with 
latlng info... Maybe this is where the problem is?

Comment: You might have to parse layer before getting the latlng from it?

Comment: I think so yes. Trying to figure out how to that now, thanks.

Comment: You can see the FeatureGroup logged in the console over here: http://casperjonker.nl/kijk_radius/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix it by running the eachLayer function twice on the jsonGroup variable like so:

```
function markersInRadius() {

    // Lat, long of trash marker on overview map
    var trashMarkerLatLng = trashMarkerOverview.getLatLng();

    // counter of the amount of markers that are within a 20 meter radius
    var pointsInRadius  = 0;

    console.log(jsonGroup);

    // Loop through each point in JSON file
    jsonGroup.eachLayer(function (layer) {

        layer.eachLayer(function (layer) {

                // Lat, long of current point
                layerLatLong = layer.getLatLng();

                // Distance from trashMarker
                // To current point in meters
                distanceFromTrashMarker = layerLatLong.distanceTo(trashMarkerLatLng);

                // See if meters is within radius
                if (distanceFromTrashMarker <= 20) {
                    pointsInRadius += 1;
                };
            });
        });
    console.log(pointsInRadius);

    // Close pointsInCircle
    };
```

Comment: I... cannot believe this worked. Seriously, I can't believe this worked. But it saved me a LOT of trouble. Thank you!